# On a $3\times 3$ matrix.

Tags: determinant

An integer matrix $M = \begin{bmatrix}
    -a& b& -c\\
    d& e& f\\
    g& h& -i
   \end{bmatrix}$ has determinant $c e g + b f g - c d h + a f h + b d i + a e i$.

Assume $0<a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h<B$ holds.

If you pick such an uniformly random matrix what is the probability that it is singular?

Comment: @Lovsovs 'integer matrix $M$'.

Comment: As B gets to be large, small.

Comment: @DougM I think of $B$ as a parameter and so probability has to be in terms of $B$.

Comment: $ceg+bfg−cdh+afh+bdi+aei= 0$ with $a\cdots i > 0 \implies cdh=ceg+bfg+afh+bdi+aei$ if we do not choose large enough values of $c,d,h$ relative to the others, it will not be singular.... If were to guess, I would say it is on the order of $\frac {1}{B^3}$

Comment: @DougM compared to general $3\times3$ (which has $\frac1{B^2}$ scaling) we get a better scaling right?